# Infinite output when I print a variable inside a loop

Tags: c++

I'm trying to convert a number input to words. I am a beginner so my code might look clunky. I also apologise for posting such a large code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = 0, number = 0;
    string num_name = "";
    cout << "Enter a number (maximum value is 1,000,000,000)" << endl;
    cin >> number;

    //To find the maximum magnitude
    while ((number / pow(10, i)) >= 1)
    {
        i++;
    }
    i--;
    int j = i;
    cout << j << endl; //Check

                       //To find which multiple of 3 i is
    int n = 0;
    while (j >= 3)
    {
        if (j % 3 == 0)
            n++;
        j--;
    }
    j = i;
    cout << j << endl; //Check
    cout << n << endl; //Check

                       //String construction
    int k = n;
    int q = 0;

    while (k >= 1)
    {
        while (j >= (3 * k))
        {
            q = (int)(number / pow(10, j));
            if (j == 2 + (3 * k))
            {
                if (q == 1) num_name += "one";
                else if (q == 2) num_name += "two";
                else if (q == 3) num_name += "three";
                else if (q == 4) num_name += "four";
                else if (q == 5) num_name += "five";
                else if (q == 6) num_name += "six";
                else if (q == 7) num_name += "seven";
                else if (q == 8) num_name += "eight";
                else if (q == 9) num_name += "nine";

                num_name += "hundred";
            }
            if (j == 1 + (3 * k))
                continue;
            if (j == 3 * k)
            {
                if (q == 1) num_name += "one";
                else if (q == 2) num_name += "two";
                else if (q == 3) num_name += "three";
                else if (q == 4) num_name += "four";
                else if (q == 5) num_name += "five";
                else if (q == 6) num_name += "six";
                else if (q == 7) num_name += "seven";
                else if (q == 8) num_name += "eight";
                else if (q == 9) num_name += "nine";
                else if (q == 10) num_name += "ten";
                else if (q == 11) num_name += "eleven";
                else if (q == 12) num_name += "twelve";
                else if (q == 13) num_name += "thirteen";
                else if (q == 14) num_name += "fourteen";
                else if (q == 15) num_name += "fifteen";
                else if (q == 16) num_name += "sixteen";
                else if (q == 17) num_name += "seventeen";
                else if (q == 18) num_name += "eighteen";
                else if (q == 19) num_name += "nineteen";
                if (q >= 20 && q <= 99)
                {
                    int r = 0;
                    r = q % 10;
                    (int)(q /= 10);
                    if (q == 2) num_name += "twenty";
                    else if (q == 3) num_name += "thirty";
                    else if (q == 4) num_name += "forty";
                    else if (q == 5) num_name += "fifty";
                    else if (q == 6) num_name += "sixty";
                    else if (q == 7) num_name += "seventy";
                    else if (q == 8) num_name += "eighty";
                    else if (q == 9) num_name += "ninety";

                    if (r == 1) num_name += "one";
                    else if (r == 2) num_name += "two";
                    else if (r == 3) num_name += "three";
                    else if (r == 4) num_name += "four";
                    else if (r == 5) num_name += "five";
                    else if (r == 6) num_name += "six";
                    else if (r == 7) num_name += "seven";
                    else if (r == 8) num_name += "eight";
                    else if (r == 9) num_name += "nine";
                }


                if (k == 3) num_name += "billion";
                else if (k == 2) num_name += "million";
                else if (k == 1) num_name += "thousand";
            }
            number = number % (int)pow(10, j);
            j--;
        }
        k--;
    }
    cout << num_name << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

The loop at the "String Construction" section crashes and is printing infinite values of the variable q (quotient). I have also tried printing a simple variable like flag = 1 before q and that too is giving infinite 1s. I cannot figure out what is causing this. Any input would be greatly helpful for my learning!

Comment: If `j == 1 + (3 * k)` then it is also true that `j >= (3 * k)` (if you substitute `j`, you get `1 + (3 * k) >= (3 * k)`). Since you `continue` on that branch you will iterate again and always fall into this branch. You never change `j` or `k` between the loop condition and that `if` so you will fall in an infinite loop. Perhaps you meant your `while` loop to be a `for` loop?

Comment: So my continue usage was wrong. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one of the best things you can do is do not messy the main function. You messed the main function :c

It's a great idea create functions that allow you to solve your problem with less code. The number of function to create is subjective, imho it would bo good create 2 function: toDigit and convert, both return strings.

Also i would use a function for the logaritm and for the power without use the libraries (mainly because power return a double that you have to convert it to int, the math library is weighty and other reason)

Let's start: (All the function must be above the main function and toDigit must be above convert)

You can get the magnitude of the number with a rudimental logaritmic function that give you a bad apporximation, beacuse of that i've called it sillyLog:

```
int sillyLog(int n, int b){
    return !(n/b < 1)? 1 + sillyLog(n/b, b) : 1;
}
```

Then we create our function for the power:

```
int power(int b, int e){
    return (e < 1)? 1 : b * power(b, e-1);
}
```

Now let's see the main:

```
int main(){
    int number = 0, magnitude = 0, counter = 1;
    string num_name = "";
    cout << "Enter a number (maximum value is 2,147,483,647)" << endl;
    cin >> number;
    magnitude = sillyLog(number, 10);
    while (magnitude - 3 > 0){
        magnitude = magnitude - 3;
        counter++;
    }
    while (number){
        int tmp;
        tmp = (number - (number % power(1000,--counter)))/ power(1000, counter);//remove all digit after the first three and decrease counter
        num_name += convert(tmp, counter + 1);
        number = number - tmp * power(1000, counter);                           // we cut the first 3 digit 
    }
    cout << num_name << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

counter is the variable that count triplets,

also 2,147,483,647 is the max length for the integer type, if you want a bigger number you have to use a long/long long/unsigned/ other types.
NB: negative numbers aren't a problem because you simply ignore them but they "eat" half of your memory dedicated to the number.

How you can see we generate our string simply calling the function convert

```
string convert(int n, int m){
    string s = "";
    s = ((n-n%100)/100)? toDigit((n-n%100)/100) + " hundred " : "";
    s += toDigit(n - (n - n%100));
    switch (m){
        case 4: return s + " billion ";
        case 3: return s + " million ";
        case 2: return s + " thousand "; 
        default: return s;
    }
}
```

I've used the conditional operator (ternary) and the switch case instead of the if just to let you know about their existence here

Now let's see the heaviest function that we can't simplify :c

```
string toDigit(int n){
    if (n < 20)
        switch (n){
            case 1: return "one ";
            case 2: return "two ";
            case 3: return "three ";
            case 4: return "four ";
            case 5: return "five ";
            case 6: return "six ";
            case 7: return "seven ";
            case 8: return "eight ";
            case 9: return "nine ";
            case 10: return "ten ";
            case 11: return "eleven ";
            case 12: return "twelve ";
            case 13: return "thirteen ";
            case 14: return "fourteen ";
            case 15: return "fifteen ";
            case 16: return "sixteen ";
            case 17: return "seventeen ";
            case 18: return "eighteen ";
            case 19: return "nineteen ";
            default: return "";
        }
    switch ((n - n%10) / 10){
        case 2: return "twenty " + toDigit(n - (n - n % 10));
        case 3: return "thirty " + toDigit(n - (n - n % 10));
        case 4: return "forty " + toDigit(n - (n - n % 10));
        case 5: return "fifty " + toDigit(n - (n - n % 10));
        case 6: return "sixty " + toDigit(n - (n - n % 10));
        case 7: return "seventy " + toDigit(n - (n - n % 10));
        case 8: return "eighty " + toDigit(n - (n - n % 10));
        case 9: return "ninety " + toDigit(n - (n - n % 10));
    }
}
```

Here is a MUST use the switch case to make readable your code

If you have any doubt i'll answer you gladly

Comment: Man! Despite Stack Overflow telling me not to give comments like 'thanks' I'm gonna say Thank you so much for this answer!  I also apologize for the late response. This gave me a strong intro to recursion and how to think in terms of functions. This is going to be an important step in my learning!